Why does GORM's AutoMigrate always alter timestamp(0) columns on each run, and how can I prevent this?
I'm using GORM with PostgreSQL, and I'm encountering an issue where GORM's AutoMigrate function always tries to alter the timestamp(0) column type every time it runs, even if the column's type is already correct.
Here’s an example of my model:
type User struct {
    ID        uint      `gorm:"type:serial"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:timestamp(0);not null;default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"type:timestamp(0);not null;default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`
}

Both CreatedAt and UpdatedAt are defined as timestamp(0), but every time I run AutoMigrate, GORM tries to alter these columns, even if they are already timestamp(0) in the database.
I want to prevent GORM from altering these timestamp(0) columns during every AutoMigrate run. I don't want to constantly have to deal with unnecessary ALTER TABLE operations like this
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "created_at" TYPE timestamp(0) USING "created_at"::timestamp(0)
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "updated_at" TYPE timestamp(0) USING "updated_at"::timestamp(0)

